# A puzzle in a form of poem

Tags: rhyme

I have created a puzzle poem from [Hello Poetry](https://hellopoetry.com/poem/417077/guess-the-passcode/) which goes:

> Befriend with me and help me find which is gone
>
> Had A to Z, still there's something wrong
>
> Swiftly search, for it's all alone
>
> J V X Q, for the sake of completing the poem

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange! You can get a badge by take a tour here, https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is

> the letter **U**, as it's the only letter of the alphabet not in the poem. (The poem pretty directly asks you for this, and the extra letters are pretty clearly there for the sake of getting all but one.)

Comment: It's actually "I missed U", since this was dedicated to my significant other. But your answer is still correct. :)

Comment: Hmm I wonder if there is a way to use JVXQ in a word, like the grammagrams you posted a while ago...